# Cпрятать окно консольного приложения

Tags: c#

Вот такой не большой кодик

```
using System;  
using System.IO;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Text;  
using ReflactionNamespace = System.Reflection;
namespace Examples.System.Net  
{  
    public class WebRequestGetExample  
    {  
        public static void Main()  
        {  
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://******/indata.php?nt=2");  
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;  
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            var path = ReflactionNamespace.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location; 
            response.Close();  
    }  
}  
}
```

требуется чтобы он выполнялся не заметно для пользователя те чтобы консолька не вылазила...

Пробывал с startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; и startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; но при компиляции выкидываются ошибки the name "startinfo" does not exist in the current context и тд, возможно не хватает чего

Comment: не очень понятно к чему они там пришли

Comment: @Keeplod читайте с «Консольные приложения бегут в консоли...» Там даже приводится код.

Comment: Вас интересует, вероятно, последний абзац.

Comment: @Keeplod там есть пример кода как скрыть консоль и описание ограничений этого подхода. Также там говорится, что если вам нужно безоконное приложение, то лучше его делать **не** консольным